# Copulas/Probability Theory

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

So I have a basic understanding of copulas but wanted to verify I'm applying things correctly to reach the correct outcomes..

1. Show that as $\theta\to\infty, C^{Fr}(u_1,u_2)\to\min(u_1,u_2)$, the co-monotonicity
   copula.
2. Consider a random vector $Y\mathbf=(Y_1,\ldots,Y_d)'$ with joint CDF $F$ and marginal CDFs $F_1,\ldots,F_d$. The copula of $Y$ is the function $C:[0,1]^d \to [0,1]$ defined by
   $$F(y_1,\ldots,y_d)=C\left(F_1(y_1),\ldots,F_d(y_d)\right).$$
  a) If we suppose that $d=1$, what is the copula of $Y_1$?
  b) Show that $C(1,\ldots,1,u_i,1,\ldots,1)=u_i$.
  c) Show that $C$ is increasing in each of its arguments.
  d) If we suppose that all $Y_i$s are independent, what is the copula of $Y$? Show formally.
  e) Let $Y=(Y_1,Y_2)'$ be Gaussian. Give the expression for the copula of $Y$. Use this expression to show that it includes the independence, co-monotonicity, and counter-monotonicity copulas.

My work/thoughts so far:

1. Where
   $$\phi^{Fr}(u)=-\log\left\lbrace{e^{-\theta u}-1\over e^{-\theta}-1}\right\rbrace, -\infty<\theta<\infty$$
   As $\theta\to\infty$, the effect of $u$ decreases, such that $\phi^{Fr}(u_1)\approx\phi^{Fr}(u_2)$, thus $C(u_1,u_2)=P(U_1\le u_1,U_1\le u_2)=\min(u_1,u_2)$.
2. a) For $d=1:C(F_1(Y_1))=F(Y_1)=P(Y_1\le y_1)$ ?
   b) I know this has to do with each $u_i$ being the marginal, and the combination thereof being required to have uniform distribution. The property makes sense to me but I'm unsure how to explain it.
   c) So I understand the intuition here: since cdfs are always increasing $C(u_1,\ldots,u_d)$ is increasing with each component $u_i$. But again I'm not sure how to formally show that.
   d) Setting $u_i=F_i(x_i)=F(x_i)$ where $F(Y)\sim U[0,1]$ (for continuous functions), we get $C(u_1,\ldots,u_i) = u_1 \times\cdots\times u_i$. 
   While this agrees with the independence copula, I feel like this is possibly missing something and/or incorrect..?
   e) I'm still working on this but think I know where I'm going with it.

Any thoughts/suggestions/references to other resources are greatly appreciated. :)